# What to do about Black Screen w/ white cursor after desktop login, Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 Bit

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I have read certain NVidia graphic cards being not-compatible. Is That the case?

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 Bit on an old system that did have XP on it, then tried Win. 8, HDs re-formatted and then installed Ubuntu 14.04 from CD, since this OLD system claimed I could boot from USB =No Go. Burned 14.04 LTS ISO Image to CD. 12 tries all failed w/ various errors, finally after launching "Try Ubuntu"; LIVE desktop, I was able to get the install process to run to completion and have a running stable OS.
 System defaulted to the Nouveau Graphics Driver.
The system is running: MSI Motherboard w/ software RAID(not used) AMD 64X 3400 CPU, Nvidia FX5500 graphics card (AGP), Sound Blaster audio card. 2- 100-GB SATA Hard drives.

Downloaded any/all updates. Also installed Synaptics package Manager.

The graphics were not good in this format. So I went ahead and selected the Proprietary(restricted) Nvidia 173.X.X.X provided w/ the ISO image and installed it, then rebooted.

After reboot: I am able to login into Home directory, Then Log into Desktop (Which has grainy graphics), after which screen goes black w/ white cursor.

I am NEW to Linux. Tried to find a solution on my own but it seems every solution was Very Specific to users situation OR solutions left out/ Assumed steps I could not follow.

I am willing to learn.

Comment: After performing: sudo NVidia-xconfig  exit command line and reboot? or just exit command line?

Answer (score 0):

It could be the case that your configuration file for X is not configured properly for the proprietary nVidia driver. Try executing `sudo nvidia-xconfig`. This will automatically create a file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` with suitable defaults and will backup any existing configuration file using the original name with `.backup` appended to the file name.

Comment: I assuming these steps were to be taken:Booted system normally, logged into home directory, logged into desktop, screen went black w/ white cursor. Pressed Ctrl+Alt+F1, logged into text line, Ran: Sudo nvidia-xconfig. Resulted in the following message: "WARNING: Unable to locate/ open X configuration file.    New X Configuration file written to "/etc/x11/xorg.conf

Comment: That's the expected warning when no configuration file is found. Did that solve your problem?

Comment: Short Answer: No
Here’s: the steps and results:
-1st and 2nd reboots: system booted to recovery menu. Unsure of next step, chose 1st option. System proceeded to Home directory Login (Graphics Grainy on 1st try, crisper on 2nd), Logged into Home directory, Login successful, system then went Black screen, No cursor w/ “Incompatible Monitor Resolution”. Unsure of how to change screen resolution form this interface. Entered Text Line: crtl+Alt+F1, then Crtl+Alt+Delete,  rebooted.

Comment: -3rd Reboot: System booted to Home directory login, login successful (Crisp Graphics), system proceeded to Desktop Login (Crisp Graphics). Screen went Black w/ White cursor. Did not want to go to Text line since I am Not familiar with Linux Text Line commands. Tapped Ctrl+Alt+Delete several times actually got the Desktop logged in screen to flash on then go Black w/ White cursor.

Comment: Couple more taps of Ctrl+Alt+Delete keys brought up a “Ubuntu has encountered an Internal Error” message box containing a LOG. Also a few seconds later an “Updates are available” Message window appeared. Not sure what to do, cancelled out of updates.
-Not sure what steps will damage the system further.

Comment: - Scrolling through the log I could glean this much: Unity had a problem. Within the Error Log, under UnreportableReason: The system contains some obsolete package versions. Please upgrade the following packages: unity, libcurl3-gnults, licunity-core-6.0-9, unity-services, unity-settings-daemon
-Also from fumbling around the logged in desktop, I was able to pull up the settings window, where I could navigate to Update software, confirmed that the system  is still running the Nvidia Restricted Proprietary driver.

Comment: -Nowhere in the error log did it contain a messages or references to incompatibility w/ the Nvidia graphics card. It could have been there buried in the computer code though.
-Not sure where to go from here or what steps to take in what order as to not make this situation worse.

Comment: After your installation did you update your packages? The only thing I can really think might be the problem here is that the version of Unity that you have installed isn't playing nice with your GPU. From the command line, you can try `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` to perform a system update from the command line. Other than that, I'm not sure what's going on with your system.